# Copy Excel Data With Source Formatting

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I recorded a macro to do this, and copied the macro code and adapted it to how I needed it.  However, my issue is that the source formatting is not kept when I paste over to the new worksheet.  What step did I miss?  It must be something to do with the `Selection.PasteSpecial` right?  Below is the non-working syntax

```
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("db1.accdb").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Pink"
For LastRow = 2 To Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
  Next LastRow
Range("A1", "M" & LastRow).Copy
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Name = "Pink"
```

Comment: Your For loop does nothing...what is it's purpose?

Comment: I am trying to copy the range that is being shown once filtered.

Comment: I understand that, but your For loop does nothing  if you need to find the LastRow just use `LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: What is `ListObjects("db1.accdb")` ? what kind of object ?

Comment: @ShaiRado - it is an embedded access table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO need for `Selection.PasteSpecial`, normal `Copy` method is sufficient.

```
Sub copyTest()

    '/ Source             Destination
    '--------             -----------
    Sheet1.UsedRange.Copy Sheet2.Cells(1, 1)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

<< --This will work for your code.>>

```
Sub Test()

    Dim LastRow     As Long
    Dim rngCopy     As Range


    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("db1.accdb").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Pink"

    Set rngCopy = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    '/ Get rid of headers
    Set rngCopy = rngCopy.Offset(1).Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count - 1)


    Set rngCopy = rngCopy.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible)



    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add after:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Pink"

    rngCopy.Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pink").Cells(1, 1)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: How would I paste it to a new sheet?  I tried to do Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet and for the Destination Pink.Cells(1,1) but that throws an errro

Comment: see the edit. I don't write tailor made code/answers, but today i am in good mood. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

1.Using referenced objects, instead of `ActiveSheet`.

2.check if `AutoFilter` was applied during last Code run. Otherwise, if applied when sheet's area is already filtered it will remove the filter from your area, and you get an error line when trying to use: 
`Sht.ListObjects("db1.accdb").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Pink"`

**Full Code**:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyFilteredObject()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Sht     As Worksheet
Dim DestSht As Worksheet

' better avoiding ActiveSheet >> use your sheet's name
Set Sht = ActiveSheet ' use Sheets("Sheet1") for example

' check if auto-filer is applied, if yes don't remove it by using AutoFilter again
If Sht.AutoFilter.FilterMode = False Then
    Selection.AutoFilter
End If

Sht.ListObjects("db1.accdb").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Pink"

' find last row
LastRow = Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' set destination sheet after current sheet
Set DestSht = Sheets.Add(after:=Sht)
DestSht.Name = "Pink"

Sht.Range("A1:M" & LastRow).Copy
DestSht.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

DestSht.Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```